# Errors: Divisible numbers code in java

Tags: java, algorithm, divider

I created a code that takes in an array of numbers and a divider and returns an array of numbers that are divisible by the divider.

```
public class EvenNumbers {
    public static int[] divisibleBy(int[] numbers, int divider) {
        int i = 0;
        int[] divisibleNumbers = new int[0];
        while (i < numbers.length){
            if (numbers[i] % divider == 0){
                divisibleNumbers.push(numbers[i]);
                i++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return divisibleNumbers;
    }
}
```

However I get an error that I dont know how to fix:
Error: cannot find symbol in the push elements statment.

If anyone knows how I could fix this 2 errors please answer in the comments, the help is much appriciated.

Comment: `if (numbers[i] % divider = 0)` --> `if (numbers[i] % divider == 0)`

Comment: oh I forgot the double equal sign oops

Comment: Java is _not_ JavaScript, you can't `push()` an element to an array.

Comment: I see, so how could I add elements to my array then so I can return the array of divisibleNumbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare with `==`, not assign the value

`if (numbers[i] % divider == 0){`

You are creating an array of [0] elements which size is not-modifiable, try using a List or a bigger array

```
List<Integer> divisibleNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Or

```
int[] divisibleNumbers = new int[numbers.length]; //since you will never get more numbers than those which are in numbers
```

And add elements as:

```
divisibleNumbers.add(element); //list
divisibleNumbers[position] = element; //array
```

Comment: This does not compile, the primitive `int` is not a valid generic type.

Comment: fixed, just use Integer instead of the primitive int

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `push()` to add elements to an array, that's JavaScript syntax.

What you want is a list, not an array, because you don't know how many elements are going to be divisible by `divider` beforehand and arrays have a fixed size.

Simplify your method to:

```
public static List<Integer> divisibleBy(int[] numbers, int divider) {
    List<Integer> divisibleNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int number : numbers) {
        if (number % divider == 0) {
            divisibleNumbers.add(number);
        }
    }
    return divisibleNumbers;
}
```

or choose for a more functional approach:

```
public static int[] divisibleBy(int[] numbers, int divider) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers)
            .filter(number -> number % divider == 0)
            .toArray();
}
```